# Как сделать переход из activity в canvas? чтобы к примеру при нажатии кнопки на main activity осуществился переход на страницу с объектами canvas

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));


    }


    class MyView extends View {
        Paint p;
        Rect rect;
        Path mPath;
        Canvas canvas;
        Picture mPicture;
        public boolean pointer;

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

            int viewWidth = w;
            int viewHeight = h;


        }


        // координаты для рисования квадрата\\
        float x = 500;
        float y = 600;
        int side = 83;
        int side2 = 138;
        int sider = 67;
        int sider2 = 72;
        float x2 = 345;
        float y2 = 580;//енные для перетаскивания
        boolean drag = false;
        float dragX = 0;
        float dragY = 0;
        float xx = 500;
        float yy = 500;

        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            p = new Paint();
            canvas = new Canvas();
            mPicture = new Picture();
            pointer = false;
            p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            rect = new Rect();
            Canvas canvas = mPicture.beginRecording(1080, 1920);
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dor);

            canvas.drawBitmap(image, 100, 100, p);


        }

        public void setPointer(boolean point) {
            pointer = point;
        }

        public void onDraw(Canvas c) {


            c.translate(0, 0);
            c.drawPicture(mPicture, new Rect(-35, 150, 350, 800));

            Bitmap image2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rr);

            c.drawBitmap(image2, x2, y2, p);

            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.keyy);

            c.drawBitmap(image, x, y, p);



        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            // координаты Touch-события
            float evX = event.getX();
            float evY = event.getY();


            switch (event.getAction()) {
                // касание началось
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // если касание было начато в пределах квадрата
                    if (evX >= x && evX <= x + side + side2 && evY >= y && evY <= y + side + side2) {

                        drag = true;
                        // разница между левым верхним углом квадрата и точкой касания
                        dragX = evX - x;
                        dragY = evY - y;
                    }
                    break;
                // тащим
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    // если режим перетаскивания включен
                    if (drag) {

                        x = evX - dragX;
                        y = evY - dragY;
                        if (evX >= x2 && evX <= x2 + sider + sider2 && evY >= y2 && evY <= y2 + sider + sider2) {
                            Canvas canvas = mPicture.beginRecording(1080, 1920);
                            Bitmap image3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dor2);
                            canvas.drawBitmap(image3, 100, 100, p);

                        }
                         invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
                // касание завершено
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // выключаем режим перетаскивания
                    drag = false;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

вот весь код страницы с канвой, скажите пожалуйста что нужно добавить чтобы осуществить переход

Comment: То есть вам нужна какая то задержка прежде чем показывать эту канву? По коду она должна сразу отображаться при старте активити

Comment: Activity и canvas это абсолютно разные вещи. Canvas может быть нарисован только на activity. Ну или фрагменте. Поэтому вы можете его нарисовать по слушатель на кнопке или открыть по кнопке второе activity, где уже есть canvas

Comment: Спасибо , всё, уже разобралась